# meta.ja.stackoverflow.comの証明書

Tags: バグ, 完了

https://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com に接続すると、証明書の検証に失敗してエラーになりますね。証明書のCN/SANにmeta.ja.stackoverflow.comをカバーするエントリがありません。

中途半端な状態でHTTPSでのサービスを継続するぐらいであれば、HTTPSでは接続できない方が好ましいです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2017年4月追記：

予定通り、メタのURLが `ja.meta.stackoverflow.com` に変更され、問題なくHTTPSで接続できるようになりました。これまでの `meta.ja.stackoverflow.com` からは301リダイレクトが行われ、投稿内に書かれたリンクも（Community♦ユーザーによる編集として）修正されています。

関連 [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)

---

`meta.*.stackoverflow.com` という証明書は発行できないため、今のURLでSSLを使えるようにするには100以上の証明書を登録・管理する必要があります。

代わりに、メタサイトのURLを `meta.*.stackoverflow.com` という形から`*.meta.stackoverflow.com` に変えることを[検討しています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/accessing-per-site-metas-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx/266711#266711)。そうすると一つの証明書で全てをカバー出来るため、問題は解決できる見込みです。

スケジュールはまだ確定していませんが、先週に開発者がフォロー中と上記の英語版の投稿にかかれています。状況をフォローしますので、情報がありましたらこの投稿を更新します。

追記：

サイト全体のSSL対応について、当社の開発者Nick Craverが2年半前にブログを書いています。

http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

上記記事に詳しく書かれているので、もし興味があればご覧ください。